# Eclipse Content Assist doesn't suggest jdk.* classes

Tags: java, eclipse, project-panama

I configured my project to use a Project Panama EA JDK, I can use jdk.incubator.foreign.* manually but Content Assist and Quick Fix don't suggest/fix anything from this package.

Is there a way to configure Content Assist or something?

(I looked into Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist, No luck there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found that eclipse by default is configured to not assist with classes named `jdk.*`.

I found this setting under Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters

[image: Config dialog]

Just remove `jdk.*` from this list.
(You may add `jdk.*.internal.*` instead)

Comment: Thank you! Turns out there is a really subtle link to that in the Content Assist settings pointing to type filters. It just wasn't that obvious.